# Tag helper field is encoded wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Consider the following tag helper (non-relevant parts hidden)

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*", Attributes = "optional-field-checkbox")]
public class OptionalFieldCheckbox : TagHelper
{
    // [...]

    [HtmlAttributeName("checkbox-label")]
    public string CheckboxLabel { get; set; }

    public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

with a call to the above tag helper as follows

```
<div optional-field-checkbox checkbox-label="L'évènement se déroule sur plusieurs jour ?">
    <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

When I retrieve the value from the `CheckboxLabel` property in the `ProcessAsync` method I get the following, wrongly encoded, string:

> L'�v�nement se d�roule-t-il sur plusieurs jour ?

The expected value would be

> L'évènement se déroule-t-il sur plusieurs jour ?

I have:

- Googled this problem and it seems this is due to double-encoding of the value by the TagHelper, but I couldn't find any solution
- Tried bypassing the encoding by using an `HtmlString` as the `CheckboxLabel`'s property's type, but it didn't change anything
- Tried using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` and `WebUtility.UrlDecode` to get the original string back, to no avail

How can I get the raw string in the `ProcessAsync` method and, if it's impossible, how can I encode the string back to its original form ?

Comment: Is your html encoding set to utf-8?

Comment: did you try to use @Html.Raw() to prevent your string from being double encoded? (checkbox-label = @Html.Raw("L'évènement se déroule sur plusieurs jour ?"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your cshtml razor file was saved with a non-UTF8 encoding.

To change the encoding, click File > Save yourfile.cshtml as... > Save with encoding; then select Unicode (UTF8).

This will probably solve your issue.

Comment: It's been a while so I'm not 100% sure, but I think that's what I ended up doing based on the comments on my question. Thus, have my green check